# WSO2 ESB/GREG High Availability

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry, wso2-esb

I’m attempting to configure WSO2 ESB/GREG in a High Availability configuration, as follows:

> Two GREG-ESB pairs, installed/configured on two separate Solaris servers.
>
> Each server has an instance of GREG 4.5.3 (port offset 0) and ESB 4.7.0 (port offset 1) installed in separate installation directories.
>
> GREG installations are configured to use ORACLE with jdbc DataSource, both connecting to the same database/schema, so adding something to one GREG is visible in the other.
>
> ESB installations are configured with remote GREGs from above (each on the same server) and pointing to the same ORACLE database/schema for configuration/governance registry artifacts.
>
> Tribes synchronization is enabled on all 4 installations.

We plan to use our own Load Balancer to round-robin traffic to either one or the other ESB with the idea that if one of the Solaris servers is down, we still have the full functionality on the other.

I couldn’t find an example of such HA configuration in WSO2 documentation.

The questions are:

> . did anyone attempt such configuration (did it work)?
>
> . is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer this  [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance453/Creating+a+Governance+Registry+Cluster#CreatingaGovernanceRegistryCluster-lb)  for information on deploying a cluster of Governance Registry instances to achieve load balancing and high availability.

To avoid the risk of system downtime due to failure of the ELB, you can implement a fail-proof ELB deployment. This [documentation](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/ELB203/Automatic+Failover) explains how to implement failover using two identical ELB setups running in active and passive modes respectively.